# read file to variable shell script

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi

I have a text file that has coordinates in it. The text file looks like this:

```
52.56747345
-1.30973574
```

What I would like to do within raspberry pi shell script is to read the file and then create two variables. One being latitude which is the first value in the text file and the second being longitude which is the second value. Im not sure how to do this so could i please get some help.

Answer (score 2):

This works ok:

```
$ { read lat;read lon; } <file
```

First line is stored in var `$lat`, second line in var `$lon`

Answer (score 0):

```
lat=$(head -1 file.txt)
echo $lat
52.56747345

lon=$(tail -1 file.txt)
echo $lon
-1.30973574
```

Answer (score 0):

1 You have a data file:

`cat data.txt`
result: 

`52.56747345
-1.30973574
42.56747345
-2.30973574
32.56747345
-3.30973574`

2 Write a shell script:
`cat tool.sh`

result:
`#!/bin/bash
awk '{if(NR%2==0) print $0;else printf $0" "}' data.txt | while read latitude longitude
do 
    echo "latitude:${latitude} longitude:${longitude}"
done`

3 Execute this shell script.Output is like this:

`sh tool.sh`

result: 

`latitude:52.56747345 longitude:-1.30973574
latitude:42.56747345 longitude:-2.30973574
latitude:32.56747345 longitude:-3.30973574`