# Shell script is unable to read groovy variable, tried multiple ways

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I am new to shell and groovy and I have already googled and read solutions below, but none of it seems to be working

[Groovy parameter to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63301406/groovy-parameter-to-shell-script)
[Pass groovy variable to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41553303/pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script)
[read file to variable shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576457/read-file-to-variable-shell-script)
[How to pass a groovy variable to a shell block jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174491/how-to-pass-a-groovy-variable-to-a-shell-block-jenkins)
[How to pass groovy variable to shell script in Jenkinsfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145602/how-to-pass-groovy-variable-to-shell-script-in-jenkinsfile)

Issue:
I want to read value from the groovy variable and pass it to shell script but either I get blank value or the literal variable name

Below is my code:

```
        def Tenant_Instances = ''
       //some more declarations and code
          if(tenant_created)
            {
  Tenant_Instances = "author.${ciTenant}.rally-dev.com,publish.${ciTenant}.rally-dev.com"
       println("tenant instance are -"+Tenant_Instances) //value coming fine here
                //some code here
           println("tenant instance again are -"+Tenant_Instances) //values coming fine here too
                  
                         sh '''#!/bin/bash
                                echo "[MNR] - Beginning deployment of bundle(s) to AEM Package Manager"
                                
                                IFS="," read -ra INSTANCES <<< $Tenant_Instances
                                echo "demo ${INSTANCES}" -->here value does not come properly
```

I have tried replacing Tenant_Instances with 'Tenant_Instances' or "${Tenant_Instances}" or $Tenant_Instances or '$Tenant_Instances'... but none of it seem to work.

Comment: Use `env.Tenant_Instances = ...` in groovy. Then `Tenant_Instances` env var will be available in shell

Comment: What you show there doesn't look like validGroovy code.  The triple quoted String that is passed as an argument to `sh` looks like it opens with `'''` but those are never closed.  Separate from that It looks like you are expecting String interpolation to happen, which would require triple double quotes (`"""`) not triple singe quotes (`'''`).

Comment: @daggett your solution worked. May I know what was the logic behind this or what was missing in my understanding?

Comment: `env` is a map of environment variables that automatically passed to any shell script. The other way described by Jeff should also work but in this case you should escape all `$` that must must be passed to shell as `\$`. Note that env could contain only strings.